# How to commit contents of a git subrepo to the parent repo

Tags: git

I have clones several repos under one git repo. The cloned repos don't show up as changes in the git diff cuz they have their own .git folder.

How can I treat all of these new git repos as changes and commit them to the parent repo?

Comment: I don't think you can. If u have multiple clones of one repo you have to do one commit for each cloned repo and resolve any possible merge when you try to push to the remote

Comment: You need to look into [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [subtrees](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt)

Comment: I've done it before - forgot how though. It involved recursively renaming/removing .git folders. I can't use submodule or subtree as that would create unnecessary commits.

Comment: Git doesn't store files, and by design *will* not store another repository. Git stores *commits* (and then each *commit* stores *every* file as a full snapshot: checking out that commit gets you those files). So if you have commits you like, send them with `git push`, and if you don't have commits you like, make new commits that you *do* like and send *those*. That's pretty much it.